# NTLM Auth switch based on User Agent?

Tags: php, user-agent, ntlm

I have a setup a [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) login but of course not every client does support NTLM. Unfortunately you can not silently ask the browser if there is a NTLM login present because the browser will display a login popup automatically. To avoid the ugly popup dialog I am thinking about a server side switch based on the user agent. I already has some IP ranges I can exclude from NTLM but I would like to look at the user agent, too.

Question is how does user agent look like where NTLM is possible?

Or is this nonsense at all?

I found a [small list](https://kb.bluecoat.com/index?page=content&id=KB4741) of agents I could exclude. Also I could exclude browser that do [not support NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication#Supported_web_browsers) at all. Probably I could also exclude everything that is not contains "Windows". [The ntlm-sso project](https://github.com/rekado/ntlm-sso#notes) suggest that the user agent needs to start with "Mozilla".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we implemented a cookie based solution instead of this. If a user chooses to use NTLM a cookie is created and everybody with this cookie is forwarded to NTLM login page. This does work nicely.